# problem using the method contains in java

Tags: java

I'm currently coding a java program and I had to use the contains method. Well, with the execution of my program I understood that I had used it badly.

My aim is to check whether my object p is in an arraylist containing objects of the same class as p. If so, I don't add it, otherwise I do.

In the end, I often have 2 parts with the same characteristics in my list (my aim is to have a list made up of parts that are different from each other).

Do I have to override the method equals? and why? What this contains method is based on?

Thanks in advance! :)

```
while (cpt < 9) {
                    boolean taille = rand.nextBoolean();
                    boolean couleur = rand.nextBoolean();
                    boolean forme = rand.nextBoolean();
                    piece3 p = new piece3(taille, couleur, forme);
                    if (!collectionPiece.contains(p)) {
                        collectionPiece.add(p);
                        cpt++;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need to override the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method because the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method relies on the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method to determine if an object is already in the list. Also, for best practices, you should also override the [`hashcode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method to be consistent with [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

One more issue is your actual loop condition it should be `< 8`, not `< 9` since there are `2 * 2 * 2 = 8` different pieces (i.e., there is an infinite loop right now ):

```
public class Piece3 {
  private boolean taille;
  private boolean couleur;
  private boolean forme;

  public Piece3(boolean taille, boolean couleur, boolean forme) {
    this.taille = taille;
    this.couleur = couleur;
    this.forme = forme;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Piece3 piece3 = (Piece3) obj;
    return taille == piece3.taille &&
        couleur == piece3.couleur &&
        forme == piece3.forme;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = Boolean.hashCode(taille);
    result = 31 * result + Boolean.hashCode(couleur);
    result = 31 * result + Boolean.hashCode(forme);
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Piece3{" +
        "taille=" + taille +
        ", couleur=" + couleur +
        ", forme=" + forme +
        '}';
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Piece3> collectionPiece = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int cpt = 0;
    while (cpt < 8) {
      boolean taille = rand.nextBoolean();
      boolean couleur = rand.nextBoolean();
      boolean forme = rand.nextBoolean();
      Piece3 p = new Piece3(taille, couleur, forme);
      if (!collectionPiece.contains(p)) {
        collectionPiece.add(p);
        cpt++;
      }
    }
    for (Piece3 piece : collectionPiece) {
      System.out.println(piece);
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
Piece3{taille=false, couleur=true, forme=true}
Piece3{taille=false, couleur=false, forme=false}
Piece3{taille=true, couleur=true, forme=true}
Piece3{taille=false, couleur=true, forme=false}
Piece3{taille=true, couleur=false, forme=true}
Piece3{taille=true, couleur=true, forme=false}
Piece3{taille=true, couleur=false, forme=false}
Piece3{taille=false, couleur=false, forme=true}
```